Whether the `shared` means all humans can understand in this sentence?
When I read a paper, there is a sentence I don't understand the shared:
people use shared, iconic representations of objects 

Whether the shared means all humans can understand?

the context:

There exists significant prior research on retrieving images or 3d
models based on sketches. The assumption in all of these works
is that, in some well-engineered feature space, sketched objects resemble
their real-world counterparts. But this fundamental assumption
is often violated – most humans are not faithful artists. Instead
people use shared, iconic representations of objects (e.g. stick figures)
or they make dramatic simplifications or exaggerations (e.g.
pronounced ears on rabbits). Thus to understand and recognize
sketches an algorithm must learn from a training dataset of real
sketches, not photos or 3d models. Because people represent the
same object using differing degrees of realism and distinct drawing
styles (see Fig. 1)


It's not a matter of these representations being simple enough that "humans can understand" them; rather "shared" means that in a given culture these iconographic representations are seen in public spaces and become part of the culture. It's interesting that in American culture animals are still represented with natural and fairly accurate silhouettes on road signs (e.g. ducks, deer crossing the road) whereas human beings, though they used to be represented with natural silhouettes on those signs (near pedestrian crossings or playgrounds), are nowadays represented with droid-like shapes.

Yes, it means that the understanding that a drawing such as a stick figure represents a human being is shared by everyone in that culture. I don't know about 'all humans' - I expect stick figures are pretty universal, but other conventions may not be. A drawing of an animal with long ears might not be recognised as a rabbit in parts of the world where there are no rabbits.
